# $f \leq g \mu$ a.e. $g$ is Lebesgue integrable and measurable, can $f$ be a non-measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given a measure space $(X, A, \mu)$ and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to have $f \leq g$, $\mu$-a.e. where $g$ is $A$-$B(\mathbb{R})$ measurable and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}gd \mu < \infty$ but $f$ is not $A$-$B(\mathbb{R})$ measurable. $B(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$.

My initial thought was to try to find a counterexample. If I let $V$ denote a non-measurable set define $f(x):= e^{x}\mathbb{1}_{V}(x) +(-e^{x}-100)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus V}(x)$. Then $f(x)$ is measurable. But then since exponentials grow quickly, I don't know what $g$ I could take to satisfy the initial assumptions.

Thanks.

Comment: Let $E$ be some non Borel-measurable subset of $[0,1]$, and $f=\mathbf{1}_E$ the indicator function, and let $g=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Take $X = [0, 1]$ with the Borel sets; define $g = 1$ here and $f = \mathbf{1}_C$ for a non-measurable $C$ there.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks both that makes sense. One follow up, how does this satisfy $f \leq g$ $\mu$ a.e.? In particular I am not seeing why $f(x) >g(x)$ on a null set (i.e. why the property does not hold on a null set)?

Comment: $f\leq g$ everywhere in mine and William M's comments. i.e the set of points where $f>g$ is empty.